# What is the best approach for large scale Paths and Funnels Analysis?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, knowledge-graph

We have a big dataset of user actions on our internal apps. I am trying to create an algorithm for Paths & Funnels analytics which will take parameters for Paths (i.e. Start and End point) and a defined step of actions for Funnel. What is the best algorithm to program this with large data? The output should be just counts of users for specific set of actions like this :

Format of the file to scan:

| UserID | Action | TS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 06/04/2022 |
| 1 | B | 06/04/2022 |
| 1 | C | 06/04/2022 |
| 1 | D | 06/04/2022 |
| 2 | G | 06/04/2022 |
| 2 | H | 06/04/2022 |
| 2 | K | 06/04/2022 |

Algorithm input parameters:

1. For Path : User statistics on the start point A and end point F
2. For Funnel: User statistics on the defined steps A->B->C->D

| Path | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A->B->C->D | 385 |
| G->H->K | 89 |

where A,B,C,D,... are nodes for user actions or pages.

This should be easy using Python for a smaller set, but the issue is, I am worried about performance, as I am dealing with millions of records like this. Please help!

Comment: Please provide a small example of the input and what the output should be for that input.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have updated the question to include sample data, parameters and output.

Comment: "User statistics on the start point A and end point F" what does this look like?

Comment: "*This should be easy using Python for a smaller set*" - please show your simple Python implementation of what the result should be, then we can help you to find a more efficient implementation/algorithm

Comment: @ravenspoint : So that means any path that starts at point A and ends in point B, where A,B could be pages or actions. It should look like this: A->C->D->B OR A->B OR A->N->M ... I want counts of users for each paths. Is that more clear?

Comment: Statistics are things like mean, or standard deviation.  It seems that all you intend is the path start point and end point.  There are no "user statistics" in the input.

Comment: It looks like you want to search the data for user that follow certain defined paths.  Unfortunately your data does not have this information.  I guess that if two rows in your data contain action A, immediately followed by B ( as in first two rows you posted ) then you assume that the user moved from A to B.  So you have to pre-process your data to capture this.  The first two rows in your post should become "1 A B 06/04/2022"  After this the problems becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

```
...
1 A ts
1 B ts
...
```

in the input data means user 1 went A -> B

the algorithm is

```
CREATE new table paths_users_followed
CREATE new path
LOOP over data input rows, except last
   IF user in row equals user in row+1
      ADD action in row to path
      IF row+1 is last row
         ADD action in last to path
         ADD user, path to paths_users_followed
   ELSE
      ADD user, path to paths_users_followed
      CREATE new PATH
ENDLOOP

LOOP P over input of "path statistics"
    COUNT occurrences of P in paths_users_followed
```

This can be most easily and efficiently implemented using a high performance database engine - I would use SQLite.

Comment: I can not upvote this, because I am new and I need min 15 reputations to upvote, but thank you so much! I have an idea to start now. Thank you once again @ravenspoint